# Proper typedef syntax in C

Tags: c, coding-style, standards

**Short Question**
Is there a proper or preferred way to to use typedefs of `structs` and `enums` in C?

**Background**
I have been working on a code base that has had several people / companies working on it and I have come across different implementations of `typedefs`.  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) they all appear to have the same function.  I guess I'm trying to understand if there are subtile differences or gotchas between them.  The same usages and question applies to `typedef`ing an `enum`.

```
// I tend to use this if I need to create an
// alias outside the defining module.

typedef struct obj obj_t;
struct obj
{
    UINT8 val;
};

// I started to use this format to alias objects
// within the same module (both private and
// public definitons).  This is also how 
// several colleagues use them.

typedef struct obj_t
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj_t;

// This is how I now typically format the aliases
// for both public and private definitions.

typedef struct
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj_t;

// I just ran into this one.  While makes sense 
// how it works, it wasn't inherently better or
// worse then the formats above. Note the different 
// container names.

typedef struct obj_t
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj;
```

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html), all names that end in `_t` are reserved so that's probably not the best code to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all basically the same, in that they all define `obj_t` as a type alias for the structure.

The difference is when you define the name of the structure (e.g. `struct obj ...`) is that you can then *also* use `struct obj myStructure;` This is needed if you want to reference the structure inside it self (like when creating a linked list for example). If you do the `typedef` before the actual structure (like in your first example) then you can of course use the typedef'd name inside the structure as well.

Comment: Your linked list is actually the only time I have used the 1st method in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Another subtile difference between your declarations is version 2 to 3. In 3, you use a typedef of an unnamed struct which is will give you an implicit cast error when you are going to cast it to let's say 2.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the implicit casting there.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct obj obj_t;
struct obj
{
    UINT8 val;
};
```

Writing the typedef before lets you use it inside the structure.

```
typedef struct obj_t
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj;

typedef struct obj_t
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj_t;
```

these two are for when you need to declare variables using either "struct obj_t" or "obj_t". I prefere using a t_ or _t for typedefs (more explicit), but it's really just a coding style matter, no technical chose to use one instead of the other.

```
typedef struct
{
    UINT8 val;
}obj_t;
```

Here you can only use the typedef since the structure has no name. Therefore you can't declare, inside your structure, a variable of this type.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't answer your question, but would instead suggest to consider what [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) has to say on the matter of typedefs. See "Chapter 5: Typedefs". Excerpt:

> Please don't use things like "vps_t".
>
> It's a *mistake* to use typedef for structures and pointers. When you see a
>
> vps_t a;
>
> in the source, what does it mean?
>
> In contrast, if it says
>
> struct virtual_container *a;
>
> you can actually tell what "a" is.
>
> Lots of people think that typedefs "help readability". Not so.

Read on for the suggested exceptions.

Comment: Good read and makes sense.  However I don't quite agree that they "can tell what 'a' actually is."  Typedef hides the fact `vps_t` is a structure but does not mitigate the need to inspect the header or docs to see how to use the `virtual_container`.

Comment: @AdamLewis yes, it doesn't help a lot, but still provides more information than just "vps_t".

Answer (score 0):

all given examples of typedefing a structure informs the same thing.Currently peoples are following all this either because of employer's style guide or for customer specific coding style.you have already given all possible struct type so i am adding ENUM only what you asked for

```
typedef enum season_t { SPRING, SUMMER, FALL, WINTER } Season;
```

for more standard answers you can look into below given link
http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~piater/Cours/Coding-Style/